# updating to addEventListerner may cause return value of function not to propagate?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I recently upgraded from classical registration using

```
element.property = function
```

to advanced registration using

```
element.addEventListener( "property", function,  bool );
```

In the function I had returned a false to to disable form submission when the user presses the enter key like this:

```
tweet_input.addEventListener( "keypress", function( event )
{ 
    if( event.keyCode === 13 )
    {
       new ModelTweet().invoke(); 
       return false;
    }
}, false );
```

However, this no longer works, and every time the user hit the enter key, the form is submitted.

The HTML looks like this:

```
  <form id="tweet" method="post" name="tweet">
    <div id="tweet_input_wrap">
      <input id="tweet_input" name="tweet" type="text" maxlength="40">
        <p id="tweet_label">Comment
        </p>
      </input>
    </div>
    <p id="tweet_button" href="javascript:void(0)">Share
    </p>
    <div id="tweet_response" class="response">
    </div>
    <div id="tweet_fill">
      <!--TWEET FILL 
      -->
    </div>
  </form>
```

I use this method on 3 other forms and it works fine.

Updating to advanced registration was the last major change I made but since the other 3 forms work well...I don't understand what the issue is.

I don't see a difference when I compare the code to the other 3 forms which work.

I also recently updated the Model for Tweet, but is is obvious the form is submitted twice, once when I do it by grabbing the Enter Key, and once when it is sumbitted internally by an "enter key post".

Odd.

```
/**
 *ModelTweet
 */

var ModelTweet = ( function() 
{
    var ModelTweetI = function ( )
    {
        this.form_elements = document.getElementById( 'tweet' ).elements, 
        this.response_element = document.getElementById( 'tweet_response' );
        this.fill_element = document.getElementById( 'tweet_fill' );

        this.text_object = new TextValidator( this.form_elements );
        this.message_object = new Message( this.response_element );
        this.effects_object= new Effects( this.response_element );

        this.ajax_object = new AjaxRequest();
        this.shared_object = new Shared();

        this.TIME = this.shared_object.get( 'TIME' );
        this.load_on = this.shared_object.get( 'load_on' );
    };
    ModelTweetI.prototype.invoke = function( ) 
    {
        if( this.load_on === 1 )
        {
            if( !this.text_object.checkEmpty() ) 
            {
                this.message_object.display( 'empty' );
                this.effects_object.fade( 'down', this.TIME );
                return false;
            }
            if( !this.text_object.checkPattern( 'tweet' ) ) 
            {
                this.message_object.display( 'tweet' );
                this.effects_object.fade( 'down', this.TIME );
                return false;
            }
        }
        var response_element = this.response_element;
        var fill_element = this.fill_element;
        this.ajax_object.invoke( this.ajax_object.serializeArray( this.form_elements ) + '&ajax_type=tweet_control', function( server_response_text ) { new AjaxResponse( server_response_text, 'tweet', response_element, fill_element ); } );
        var tweet_input = document.getElementById( 'tweet_input' );
            tweet_input.value='';
            tweet_input.blur();
        }
    };
    return ModelTweetI;
} ) ();
```

Comment: Are any errors showing up in the Console?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the `submit` event on the `tweet` form rather than `keypress` on the input?  I'm no expert on form events, but why would returning false on a keypress cancel submission of the form? (If it should, forgive my ignorance.)

Comment: no errors in the console...i'm blind

Comment: it's an ajax call that sends the form information...not a post submit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value of the event handler does not do anything when used with `addEventListener()` so returning false is not designed to do what you are trying to do.

If you want to prevent the default behavior, then you need to call `event.preventDefault()` (and possibly `event.stopPropagation()` too) like this:

```
tweet_input.addEventListener( "keypress", function( event )
{ 
    if( event.keyCode === 13 )
    {
       new ModelTweet().invoke(); 
       event.preventDefault();
    }
}, false );
```

Note: this syntax doesn't work in older versions of IE that don't support `addEventListener` or `event.preventDefault()`.  They have their own way of doing things with `attachEvent` and `window.event.returnValue = false;`.

Comment: event.stopPropagation() not event.stopPrpagation()

Comment: @HBP - I fixed the typo, but in the future, you can just propose the edit directly with the edit link.